# BIP39 Path in Ledger Nano S

Tags: address, ledger-hardware-wallet

On a Ledger Nano S, you are given a BIP39 24 word mnemonic. What is the path to the address used? Is it m/44'/144'/0'/0/0 ?

Say for example I use the address generated by the Ledger Nano S to store ripple. But then I lose the device. I can generate an infinite number of addresses from the mnemonic, but I'd like to know which default path address holds the tokens.

Comment: I think this question is more suitable to the bitcoin stack exchange than cryptography SE. This has nothing to do with actual cryptography, only with deterministic wallet conventions.

Comment: In general this depends on the (software) wallet you're using to manage the device, not the hardware device itself.

Comment: Do you really mean BIP 44? If so see https://github.com/satoshilabs/slips/blob/master/slip-0044.md that maps 144 to Ripple. Unfortunately, private keys used by Ripple are neutered to be very weak, and Ripple had to dork with the the base58check-encode mappings used most all other cryptos.

Answer (score 1):

**Ledger Nano S** supported path is: **m/49'|84'/0'/0'**.
Source: https://walletsrecovery.org/